# Is the instructions made up of programs?

Tags: solana-program

I am getting confused while reading if program is made up of instructions or instructions are made up of program , or is it completely two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "instruction" tends to get overloaded.

In the purest form, a Solana **transaction** is made up of one or more **instructions**.

An instruction just describes a program invocation. Let's use an analogy: If a program is like a function, then a transaction instruction is like a function call.

Transaction instructions define the target program and all the required accounts and instruction data to invoke that program.

[image]

(Stolen from my own [blog post](https://blog.labeleven.dev/anatomy-of-solana-program-invocations-using-anchor))

#### Anchor

Things get a bit muddy when you mix in Anchor. Anchor lets you define multiple *methods* within a single program. Sometimes these methods are referred to as "instructions". But that's very confusing so I personally tend to avoid that for this very reason.

Those methods are used as a way to route the incoming instructions to the right piece of logic logic.